# `AcquireTokenAsync` returns 407

Tags: .net, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

How can I add a proxy to an `AcquireToken` method?

```csharp
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    const string AUTHORITY_URL =
        @"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenancy ID}/oauth2/authorize";
    const string RESOURCE_URL = @"https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";
    const string CLIENT_ID = @"{Client ID}";

    var credential = new UserPasswordCredential("username", "password");
    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY_URL);
    var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(RESOURCE_URL, CLIENT_ID, credential);
    return View();
}
```

When this is run it's yellow-screening with:

```
The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
```

However, there doesn't seem to be any way I can add proxy information to the `AuthenticationContext` the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do that in `web.config` instead.

```
<configuration>  
  <system.net>  
    <defaultProxy>  
      <proxy  
        usesystemdefault="true"  
        proxyaddress="http://user:pass@192.168.1.10:3128"  
        bypassonlocal="true"  
      />  
      <bypasslist>  
        <add address="[a-z]+\.contoso\.com" />  
      </bypasslist>  
    </defaultProxy>  
  </system.net>  
</configuration>
```

(from the [.NET docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings))